# Live on different time zones vs. Live in different time zones

Tags: prepositions

How are *on* and *in* different in the following:

> We live *on* different time zones
>
> We live *in* different time zones

Answer (score 2):

> We live *in* different time zones

This is the correct form. You live *in* a defined area.

You could use *on* if you were physically on top of something.

> We live *on* the continent

Comment: Your answer to the time zones question is accurate, but you've oversimplified how the word "on" can be used. I can be _on_ the telephone, _on_ hold, waiting for someone _on_ the other end. I can live _on campus_, but, in that case, "on" means _within the confines of_, more than it means _physically on top of._ I can live _on_ a mountain, but that doesn't mean I live "on top" of the mountain. Radios and light bulbs can be "on the table," or they can simply be _on_. And on and on it goes.